# The centralizer of a normal state on a type III$_1$ factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $M$ be any type III$_1$ factor.

Does there must exist a normal state $\rho$ on $M$ such that the centralizer $M_{\rho}$ of $\rho$ is a factor?

Answer (score 5):

The recent preprint "Ergodic states on type III$_1$ factors and ergodic actions" ([arXiv:2305.14217](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.14217)) of Stefaan Vaes and myself answers your question. We show that every III$_1$ factor with separable predual admits a faithful normal state $\phi$ such that $M_\phi=\mathbb{C}$ (in fact such states are generic). A key ingredient in the proof is Connes-Stormer theorem which implies that for *every* faithful normal state $\phi$ on a type III$_1$ factor, the centralizer of the ultrapower state $\phi^\omega$ is a II$_1$ factor.

Note also that the Connes' bicentralizer conjecture (which is known to hold for a very large class of type III$_1$ factors) says that every type III$_1$ factor with separable predual $M$ admits a faithful normal state $\phi$ such that $(M_\phi)' \cap M=\mathbb{C}$. See the celebrated article of Haagerup "Conne’s bicentralizer problem and uniqueness of the injective factor of type III$_1$",  Acta Math. 158: 95-148 (1987). DOI: [10.1007/BF02392257](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392257) for details.